# How to set new default name for UV map?

Tags: uv

My workflow is heavily connected with Maya and Maya has default uv name map1.
Often I have problem with renaming uvs after importing from maya.
How to set default blender uv map name to map1?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is only one answer for this:

The default identifier **UVMap** is hardcoded and there is no way to define this value individually *(Except maybe compiling a modified version of Blender)*.

But you can use python to rename the map before export (see answer of *Jakemoyo*)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to accomplish this task for you. I would really recommend whenever you have time to start looking into Python scripting, and the Blender API. Stuff like this where you "just wish it had this certain feature" to fit your certain use case becomes something you can accomplish with like 15 minutes of work.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Export Object to Maya",
    "description": "Script to reconfigure FBX export to work better with Maya defaults",
    "author": "Jake Mobley",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Export > Export Object to Maya",
    "category": "Export",
}

import bpy


class BlenderToMayaExporter(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Renames UVMap before exporting to Maya"""
    bl_idname = "object.export_to_maya"
    bl_label = "Export Object to Maya"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):

        # Goes through each selected object,
        # Goes through each uv layer in each object,
        # renames it to "map + 'layernumber' "
        # Then when that's done it calls the FBX export dialog.
        # I'll leave it to you to research  how to change it to 
        # a different file format if FBX isn't what you wanted.

        objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
        for obj in objs:
            uvs = obj.data.uv_layers
            for i,  u in enumerate(uvs):
                old_name = u.name
                new_name = f'map{i+1}'
                obj.data.uv_layers[i].name = new_name
                
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(BlenderToMayaExporter.bl_idname, text=BlenderToMayaExporter.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderToMayaExporter)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderToMayaExporter)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Put this text into your Blender script editor. Save it somewhere you can remember as like "export_to_maya.py". Make sure it has the ".py" at the end.

Once it's saved, go to **Edit > Preferences > Addons > Install**, find that file in the location you put it select it. Then check the box to enable it. I usually like to go to the bottom left to **Save Preferences** just to be sure it stays saved. Then this option should always be available to you in your export options. Let me know if it works out for you.

[image]

Comment: I searched and i found it, thank you so much Jakemoyo! It works for me)